# Redirecting to a new page based on an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax with jQuery to make a request from a page on my site. Now if the login failed (or the call failed for a different reason), I return an error message and put it in a label.  But if the call succeeds, I want to navigate to another page.  My issue is that if the call succeeds, I end up with the text of the new page in my label.

Here's my Javascript:

```
 $.post("chklogin.php", { username: username, password: password }, function(data) {
        $('#msg').html(data);
 });
```

And here's the PHP that it calls:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
    $msg="<h3>Enter valid Username and Password.</h3>";
    echo $msg;
} else {
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION["userid"]=$row["pgmail"];
    header("location:user.php");
}
```

Comment: If u can't answer don't reduce my reputation. Else better to respond with reason.

Comment: The downvotes are probably due to the poor quality of the question.  It's difficult to understand what the issue is.

Comment: I am getting response from my php file. and that I am printing on screen in label with id `msg` but if my condition is true in that case I don't want response but I want to navigate it to another page. that is `user.php`. I hope you got it better now.

Comment: I've tidied up the question a bit: I believe that it still asks the question you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this issue could have been clearer, and I would encourage you to check your spelling and code before you post again.

The issue is that you haven't sent the page to redirect, you have sent the page being called to redirect.

To fix this issue:

Firstly, get rid of the header redirect on your PHP code and replace with:

```
echo 'SUCCESS';
```

Secondly, change your AJAX code to the following:

```
 $.post("chklogin.php", { username: username, password: password }, function(data) {
      if(data=='SUCCESS'){
         window.location.href = "user.php";
      }else{
         $('#msg').html(data);
      }
 });
```

This will make the page redirect, not the page called by AJAX.